# Do the ponies of Equestria have non-exile space travel?

Tags: space, my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

In the first story arc of My Little Pony: Friendship is Magic,

> Luna returns from her 1,000 year exile on the Moon.

Is there any indication that the ponies of Equestria have access to space travel in any way, whether technological or magical, that they can use *voluntarily* to visit the Moon, another planet, or even another star system?

Comment: As far as I know, that isn't something that happens in the series. *BUT*, there IS a Fimfiction story about this exact topic. Two, in fact. One is called "Changeling Space Program" and the other is "The Maretian". "The Maretian" is a sequel to "Changeling Space Program" and is an alternate-universe of "The Martian", that really good sci-fi book/movie. Here's the links: https://www.fimfiction.net/story/327551/changeling-space-program for "Changeling Space Program"; https://www.fimfiction.net/story/396744/the-maretian for "The Maretian".

Answer (score 9):

In season 5, episode 21, *Scare Master*, Rainbow Dash is seen wearing a costume that appears to be a space suit of some kind:

[image: Rainbow Dash dressed as an astronaut]

This suggests that ponies have at least dreamed up the idea of space travel, though it doesn't *necessarily* mean they have developed the technology or magic necessary to actually pull it off.

*In the show itself* there does not (as of season 6) appear to be any further, more compelling evidence that might suggest ponies have access to space travel.

In the officially-licensed *comics* however things are a bit different, as there is actually an example of magically-assisted space travel in the main *Friendship is Magic* comic series, [Issue #6](http://mlp.wikia.com/wiki/Nightmare_Rarity_(story_arc)#Issue_.236).

In this story Celestia magically lassos the moon, and she and Luna use their powers to pull it closer to the ground:

[image: Celestia and Luna pull the Moon closer to Earth]

The main cast are then able to tightrope across the lasso in order to get to the moon (except for Fluttershy, Rainbow Dash, and Luna, who are able to simply fly there):

[image: Tightroping to the Moon]

It's up to you whether or not you consider the comics canon.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't kept up with the last two seasons, however, they didn't have any way to voluntarily visit the moon that I can recall. They were able to move through alternate universes, and there's nothing saying they can't visit planets or moons, after all, they have a spell that lets one travel through time.

Comment: Can you point to any quotes or scenes backing up your statement that the ponies can "move through alternate universes"?

Comment: @RobertColumbia: The Equestria Girls series of animated films is a prime example of Twilight Sparkle moving between different universes. They're available for streaming on Netflix if you haven't seen them yet.